# poll() returns both, POLLPRI & POLLERR

Tags: c, interrupt-handling, openwrt

I started to get in C programming with Linux and embedded systems (router hardware and openwrt). I have got interupts on GPIOs enabled, using poll works ... nearly.

I can use poll() and if i press the button to trigger the interrupt, poll() returns with a value > 0. So far so good. Now i try to use poll() on several GPIOs simultaniosly and therefor want to analyze the revents of every potential interrupt source. Allthough the interrupt seems to work, i get POLLPRI & POLLERR back and i do not understand why. Reducing the pollfd structure to 1 entry does not change anything.

```
char value;

int fd_btn1 = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio14/value", O_RDONLY);
int fd_left = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio12/value", O_RDONLY);
int fd_right = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio13/value", O_RDONLY);

struct pollfd fds[3];
fds[0].fd = fd_btn1;
fds[1].fd = fd_left;
fds[2].fd = fd_right;
fds[0].events = POLLPRI;
fds[1].events = POLLPRI;
fds[2].events = POLLPRI;

read(fd_btn1, &value, 1);
read(fd_left, &value, 1);
read(fd_right, &value, 1);

ret = poll(fds, 1, 10000);
//debugging purpose
printf("ret: %i - revents[0]: %i", ret, fds[0].revents);
```

In case button was pressed (interrupt triggered):
ret=1d, revents=10d

In case nothing was pressed, both is 0d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found some answer alluding to your question at:  http://e2e.ti.com/support/dsp/davinci_digital_media_processors/f/716/t/182883

> I just ran into the POLLERR thing you're seeing too. Turns out this is
>   how all sysfs files work, and you're using gpio through the sysfs
>   interface.
>
> From the sysfs GPIO kernel document: If the pin can be configured as
>   interrupt-generating interrupt and if it has been configured to
>   generate interrupts (see the description of "edge"), you can poll(2)
>   on that file and poll(2) will return whenever the interrupt was
>   triggered. If you use poll(2), set the events POLLPRI and POLLERR.
>   Also, if you look take a look at the kernel code in fs/sysfs/file.c,
>   you'll see that sysfs_poll returns DEFAULT_POLLMASK | POLLERR |
>   POLLPRI.
>
> All that said, it does seem strange that sysfs files return
>   POLLERR, I'm not sure why they chose to do that.

Comment: In linux, this seems to be done in the kernfs_fop_poll function in fs/kernfs/file.c. It simply always sets POLLERR for anything in sysfs. Also, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt have a bit of info, though not particularly about POLLERR.

Comment: I did some digging and I think I figured it out: the `POLLERR` is an implementation choice leaking through (because `poll` and `select` are wrappers around the same kernel API), not the result of intentional design decisions about what's best for the `poll` interface. See [the original commit that added this feature for sysfs files](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4508a7a734b111b8b7e39986237d84acb1168dd0) and the "Correspondence between select() and poll() notifications" section in [the `select` manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

Comment: Basically, it looks like returning `POLLERR|POLLPRI` was the smallest number of `poll` event bits that would cause the `select` system call to return regardless of which file descriptor sets the sysfs file was in.

Comment: (This is why people shouldn't be allowed to do too much low-level development without enough higher-level API development to balance it out - it damages the brain into tunnel-visioning on "what's the smallest change that achieves the behavior I want" and "what's the change that makes the most sense in the bowels of the implementation" and never asking "but does this result in an interface that best expresses the 'semantics' - the big-picture idea - the intent that *the user* has when reaching for this feature?")

Comment: The most charitable perspective is that 1) there was literally no better set of bits which *both* caused `select` to signal the FD as ready regardless of what FD set it was in *and* wasn't actively misleading when returned as-is from `poll` and 2) there was no great way to have `poll` omit that `POLLERR` or otherwise change the event bits in the poll set before returning it to userspace.

Comment: Ultimately the question to ask here is: if the kernel code paths for `poll` didn't also effect `select`, would anyone think that `POLLERR` was a sensible way to say "this magic file has changed" (or "you should re-open and re-read this magic file to get the latest contents now")? Judging by the number of questions where people express confusion about `POLLERR`, I think the answer is probably no, but I could see a reach/stretch argument for "this file needs to be *re-opened* to get the latest contents" being a sufficiently exceptional situation to warrant the `POLLERR` flag.